# Android MediaPlayer Error (100,0) - CFContent MP4 video

Tags: android, coldfusion, android-mediaplayer, android-video-player, android-videoview

I have an Android app which plays MP4 files from a remote server.  This works fine when providing a direct link to the mp4 file as the value for the videoview setVideoURI, however in an attempt to improve security on the video files they have been moved to a secure directory and I'm attempting to use

```
<cfcontent type="video/mp4" file="FULL VIDEO FILE PATH" deleteFile="no">
```

The video files play in a browser using this method, however in Android I get the following error in logcat.

```
11-13 10:15:58.288: D/MediaPlayer(793): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
11-13 10:15:59.318: W/AudioSystem(793): AudioFlinger server died!
11-13 10:15:59.318: W/IMediaDeathNotifier(793): media server died
11-13 10:15:59.328: E/MediaPlayer(793): error (100, 0)
11-13 10:15:59.328: E/MediaPlayer(793): Error (100,0)
11-13 10:15:59.328: D/VideoView(793): Error: 100,0
```

Looking into the error 100 - it looks to be MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED.  Is this because the cfcontent tag loads the video into memory first before sending to client?  Is there anyway around this or anything I can try?

The URL that is being passed to the videoview is something like "http://www.myserver.com/video.cfm?v=VIDEOFILENAME.mp4" which server side creates a cfcontent tag with the full path to the video and the type set to video/mp4.

Thank you!!

Comment: It would help to know what the response looks like. It sounds like the server is refusing to serve the media (sending a failure response). Can you use AndroidHttpClient to make a request similar to what the `MediaPlayer` would and check what the server is sending back?

Comment: FYI, the "Couldn't open file on client side" will happen whenever you play a network stream. In the `setDataSource` method, Android checks to see if the URI leads to a local resource first and only resorts to network activity if that isn't the case.

Comment: Sorry about the barrage of comments... but I realized the server is under your control. It may be simpler to check the request and response on the server side without writing any test code for the device.

Comment: @Dave, thank you for your suggestions.  I made a request to the mp4 file using the AndroidHttpClient and the response made me realize that my ColdFusion script was redirecting the user to the login page, as the response contained the HTML markup for my login page.  I've removed the Session check that was causing that to happen, and now when I try I get an error in logcat of MediaPlayer (1, -2147483648) which looks to be that the video is not encoded in baseline profile.  I've updated it, however I still get the error.  If I link to the file directly instead of using cfcontent it works

Comment: Why do you think the -2147483648 means it's not in baseline profile? Are you getting the response you'd expect now, with the correct headers and video data as content?

Comment: @Dave, the Google searches I've done for the above error code all lead me to posts where the solution seems to have been encoding the video in Baseline profile.  That's why I assumed the error meant the same for me.